# Is it possible to use a mod_rewrite server variable inside a RewriteCond's CondPattern?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), I'd like to use a Server Variable as part of the `CondPattern` of a `RewriteCond`, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^%{SERVER_NAME} [NC]
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This would be really useful.  I know that the `CondPattern` is a Perl-compatible Regular Expression, and that that means for example the `{}` chars in my example would need to be escaped somehow.  I've left it as-is simply to demonstrate the idea.

The aforementioned docs don't mention anything about it as far as I can find, and googling around I wasn't able to find anything definitive.  My hunch is the answer is *no*, but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CondPattern` does not expand `%{VAR}` variables or `%N` backreferences to the previous `RewriteCond`, so David's suggestion

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !%1
```

will succeed whenever `%{HTTP_HOST}` does not contain the literal string `%1`, which is not what you want.

What you want, according to your example

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^%{SERVER_NAME} [NC]
```

is to match if `HTTP_HOST` does not start with `SERVER_NAME` (case-insensitive). You can implement this with a single `RewriteCond` if you include `SERVER_NAME` in the `TestString`, capture it in the regex, and use `\N` to reference it again:

```
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_NAME} %{HTTP_HOST}" "!(^[^ ]*) \1" [NC]
```

The regex uses a space to separate `SERVER_NAME` and `HTTP_HOST` because neither variable can have spaces.

### Apache expressions (version 2.4 and later)

If you actually just want to test if `SERVER_NAME` equals `HTTP_HOST`, it would be simpler to use [Apache expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html):

```
# Case-sensitive comparison.
RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP_HOST} == %{SERVER_NAME}"
```

or

```
# Case-insensitive comparison.
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{HTTP_HOST}) == tolower(%{SERVER_NAME})"
```

Comment: The Apache expressions feature is available as of Apache 2.4 so if it doesn't work for you check your Apache version. (the documentation link points to a V2.4 page but the documentation on that page doesn't explicitly state that the feature is for 2.4 and later.)

Comment: Good catch @benrifkah, I just checked and indeed Apache Expressions are new with 2.4. [New features in Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_4.html) confirms this where it says **General-purpose expression parser**. Just edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use the variable directly like that, but what you can do is something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !%1
```

The first line should always match and captures the SERVER_NAME. The second line then uses that captured value to compare against HTTP_HOST.

Comment: This does not work. You can't use `%1` (backreference) in the CondPattern, for the same reason "you can't use the variable directly". The `%1` is not evaluated and is seen as a literal string.